# Match specific lines

Tags: regex, vb.net

Is there a shorter way of writing this with or without regex?

```
Dim q1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(myString, 
       "[\n\r]finished", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
If (q1.Success) Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Rather than **just** giving us the existing code, why not tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: belongs on code golf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
If (Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, "(?i)\nfinished")) Then Exit Sub
```

(it should be enough to check for `\n` unless you're also targeting old Macs (pre-OS X) files that only use `\r` for newlines)

Comment: I like this short version! is there a possible way of doing the exact same thing without regex just for learning purposes..

Comment: Well yes - convert the entire string to lowercase, then check if you can find `"\nfinished"` in it.

Comment: anyways to see some samples?

Comment: Hm, according to the docs, `If (LCase(myString).Contains("\nfinished"))` should do it.

Comment: is that vb.net? because \n is not used for new lines

Comment: @XK8ER: Ah yes, it seems you need `Environment.Newline` for this, then.